# Azure Mobile Services + Data with Guids

Tags: azure

I'm trying to make a table work with Guid ids instead of bigint, and different name than id, is this possible to use Guids and different id name for the client model?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. From what I know, "id" column is system generated and it is bigint (with auto increment). You could possibly have another "id" type column in your model and query based on that.

Comment: I see I think I will have to do that, maybe this can be solved using scripts but I would not like to do that, thanks